# How to append a part to query based of if else conditions within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

What I have to achieve is something like appending string to existing variable for e.g. :

```
string abc = "good";
abc += "afternoon";
```

so that the final output will be "good afternoon"

I have written the following stored procedure :

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getPropertyContactUsDetails]
    (@isDeleted CHAR(1), 
     @cName VARCHAR(MAX)) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --DECLARE @mainQ varchar(max)

    SELECT 
        pcd.col1, pcd.col2,.....
        CASE
           WHEN pcd.col1 = 'abc'
              THEN (SELECT pname FROM tbl_pd1 WHERE id = pcd.id)
           WHEN pcd.col2 = 'def'
              THEN (SELECT pname FROM tbl_pd2 WHERE id = pcd.id)
        END AS 'pname',
    FROM  
        tbl_pcd pcd 
    WHERE 
        pcd.isDeleted = @isDeleted
```

Now I want to append a part to the query based on if else condition as following:

```
IF @cName IS NOT NULL
THEN
```

append following part to the select query :

```
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

IF @cName IS NULL then don't append the part!

I have tried with declaring a parameter as :

```
DECLARE @mainQ VARCHAR(MAX)
```

Then I am doing something like :

```
SET @mainQ = 'The select statement as specified above in the stored procedure'
```

T
hen for append part :

```
IF @cName IS NOT NULL
    SET @mainQ = @mainQ + ' ORDER BY ID DESC'

END (END statement of stored procedure)
```

Can anyone help me out with the following situations, how to append a part to original query based on if else condition??

Note that stored procedure may contain multiple if statements!

Comment: I, honestly, have no idea what you're trying to achieve here. YOu seem to be trying to portray an "idea" to us, rather than what your actual goal is and showing us your actual SQL. Give us the actual statement, and explain your goal, not an idea and snippets the don't make sense.

Comment: @Larnu i am trying to achieve string append functionality within SP. Please go through my updated question

Comment: Your edit doesn't add anything to the post. Like i said, Include all the relevant parts, not just the "idea" and incomplete SQL that is never going to work.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want add to order by clause then you can use something like -

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN @cName IS NOT NULL 
  THEN ID 
  END DESC
```